# How to import an array of strings to a datagridview or Datatable?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, dataset

In VB.net
How to import an array of data to a Datagridview or a DataTable (or a Dataset)?

Initially i wanted to import data from xlsm file to a Datagridview or a Datatable, although a OleDbConnection it seems trough "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source" has a limit of 255 columns! and my data has around 3000 rows and 550 columns.

So i changed the approach to a .csv file trough " IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)" as seen in the code below, although i'm sure there is a faster cleaner way of coding, can you please help to import an array of data to a Datagridview or a DataTable (or a Dataset)?

```
    Dim lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
    Dim tbl = New DataTable
    Dim colCount = lines.First.Split(","c).Length

    Dim Novalinha As Integer
    Novalinha = 0

    For i As Int32 = 1 To colCount
        tbl.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column_" & i, GetType(String)))
    Next

    'For Each linha In lines
    '    Dim Items As String() = linha.Split(",")
    '    For i = 0 To colCount - 1
    '        tbl.Columns.Item(0).DefaultValue = Items(i)
    '    Next i
    '    tbl.Rows.Add(1)
    'Next

        DataGridView1.ColumnCount = colCount + 1
        DataGridView1.RowCount = lines.Length

        Novalinha = 0
        For Each linha In lines
            Dim Items As String() = linha.Split(",")
            For i = 0 To colCount - 1
                DataGridView1.Item(i, Novalinha).Value = Items(i)
            Next
            Novalinha += 1
        Next
```

I managed to get Datagridview of all the data, but i cant get it how to use a datatable or dataset.

Comment: See: [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) (more lightweight) and [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) (more general-purpose). You can install them using Visual Studio's `NuGet Package Manager`. You won't need any CSV conversion.

Comment: Thanks Jimi, im going to give this a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For Each linha In lines
    Dim Items As String() = linha.Split(",")
    Dim newRow As DataRow = tbl.NewRow
    For i = 0 To colCount - 1
        newRow("Column_" & (i+1).ToString) = Items(i)
    Next i
    tbl.Rows.Add(newRow)
Next
tbl.AcceptChanges
```

Then set your datagridview's datasource to tbl

```
DatagridView1.DataSource = tbl
```

Remove these lines

```
'DataGridView1.ColumnCount = colCount + 1
'DataGridView1.RowCount = lines.Length

'Novalinha = 0
'For Each linha In lines
'    Dim Items As String() = linha.Split(",")
'    For i = 0 To colCount - 1
'        DataGridView1.Item(i, Novalinha).Value = Items(i)
'    Next
'    Novalinha += 1
'Next
```

Comment: Thanks F0r3v3r-A-N00b, but i'm getting an exeption in here " newRow("Column_" & i.ToString) = Items(i)":"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Column 'Column_0' does not belong to table ."